# Plotly in Shiny Problems

Tags: colors, shiny, zooming, plotly, multi-dimensional-scaling

I am having a few problems with my Shiny which uses plotly to present the Multidimensional Scaling results.. Below is my code. An answer to any of my questions would be great, thanks in advance.

```
library(shinythemes)
library(devtools)
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)    



# UI for People
shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin="yellow", dashboardHeader(title = "MDS"),
dashboardSidebar(fluidRow(column(12,selectInput("position", label = "Choose    Position", choices = c("Forward" = "Forward", "Back" = "Back")))),
                 uiOutput("Player"),
                 fluidRow(column(12, offset = 3, actionButton("go", "Plot Players", style = "color: #00004c;")))),
dashboardBody(fluidRow(column(12, plotlyOutput("plot"))),
              fluidRow(column(2, checkboxInput("checkbox", "See Player Details", value = FALSE))),
              fluidRow(column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('tableData'))))                 ))


# Server for people

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
People <- read.csv("People.csv", header = TRUE)
Forward = People[People$Position == "Forward",]
Back = People[People$Position == "Back",]
# Changing factors to characters
People$Initials = as.character(People$Initials)
People$Player = as.character(People$Player)

output$Player <- renderUI({
players = People[People$Position == input$position,1]  

players1 = c("All Players", players)

selectInput("players", "Select Players", players1, multiple = TRUE) })

# Presaved data sets by column value Position
positionInput <- reactive ({
switch(input$data,
       "Forward" = Forward,
       "Back" = Back)})

data <- eventReactive(input$go, {
if (is.null(input$players)) return()
else if(input$position == 'Forward')
{if (input$players=="All Players"){
    Dataplayers = Forward
    players.rows = row.names(Forward)
    cms = cmdscale(dist(Forward[, c(7:10)]), k=2, eig=TRUE)
    p1 <- cms$points[players.rows,1] 
    p2 <- cms$points[players.rows,2]
    xlim = c(min(cms$points[,1]), max(cms$points[,1]))
    ylim = c(min(cms$points[,2]), max(cms$points[,2]))
    df = isolate(cbind(p1, p2, Dataplayers))
    info = list(df = df, players.rows = players.rows, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, Dataplayers = Dataplayers)
    return(info)
  }

  picked = isolate(input$players)  # Return on selected players
  Dataplayers = Forward[Forward$Player %in% picked,]
  players.rows = row.names(Forward[Forward$Player %in% picked,])
  cms = cmdscale(dist(Forward[, c(7:10)]), k=2, eig=TRUE)
  p1 <- cms$points[players.rows,1] 
  p2 <- cms$points[players.rows,2]
  xlim = c(min(cms$points[,1]), max(cms$points[,1]))
  ylim = c(min(cms$points[,2]), max(cms$points[,2]))
  df = isolate(cbind(p1, p2, Dataplayers))
  info = list(df = df, players.rows = players.rows, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, Dataplayers = Dataplayers)
  return(info)
}

else if(input$position == 'Back')
{
  if (input$players=="All Players"){
    Dataplayers = Back
    players.rows = row.names(Back)
    cms = cmdscale(dist(Back[, c(7:10)]), k=2, eig=TRUE)
    p1 <- cms$points[players.rows,1] 
    p2 <- cms$points[players.rows,2]
    xlim = c(min(cms$points[,1]), max(cms$points[,1]))
    ylim = c(min(cms$points[,2]), max(cms$points[,2]))
    df = isolate(cbind(p1, p2, Dataplayers))
    info = list(df = df, players.rows = players.rows, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, Dataplayers = Dataplayers)
    return(info)
  }

  picked = isolate(input$players)  # Return on selected players
  Dataplayers = Back[Back$Player %in% picked,]
  players.rows = row.names(Back[Back$Player %in% picked,])
  cms = cmdscale(dist(Back[, c(7:10)]), k=2, eig=TRUE)
  p1 <- cms$points[players.rows,1] 
  p2 <- cms$points[players.rows,2]
  xlim = c(min(cms$points[,1]), max(cms$points[,1]))
  ylim = c(min(cms$points[,2]), max(cms$points[,2]))
  df = isolate(cbind(p1, p2, Dataplayers))
  info = list(df = df, players.rows = players.rows, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, Dataplayers = Dataplayers)
  return(info)
 }})


output$plot <- renderPlotly({

if (is.null(data())) return() # i.e. if action button is not pressed

else if(input$position == 'Forward'){

  playerData = data()$df

  ax <- list(
    zeroline = FALSE,
    showline = TRUE,
    showticklabels = FALSE,
    mirror = "ticks",
    gridcolor = toRGB("white"),
    zerolinewidth = 0,
    linecolor = toRGB("black"),
    linewidth = 2
  )

  p = plot_ly(playerData, x = p1, y = p2, mode = "markers",
              color = Sex, colors=c("blue","goldenrod2"),
              hoverinfo = "text", text = paste ("", Player , "<br>" , "Country: " , Country ),
              source = "mds") %>%

    layout(plot_bgcolor='transparent') %>% 
    layout(paper_bgcolor='transparent') %>%
    config(displayModeBar = T) %>% # Keep Mode bar
    layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ax) # No Axis
  p

}

else if(input$position == 'Back'){

  playerData = data()$df

  ax <- list(
    zeroline = FALSE,
    showline = TRUE,
    showticklabels = FALSE,
    mirror = "ticks",
    gridcolor = toRGB("white"),
    zerolinewidth = 0,
    linecolor = toRGB("black"),
    linewidth = 2
  )

  p = plot_ly(playerData, x = p1, y = p2, mode = "markers",
              color = Sex, colors=c("blue","goldenrod2"),
              hoverinfo = "text", text = paste ("", Player , "<br>" , "Country: " , Country ),
              source = "mds") %>%

    layout(plot_bgcolor='transparent') %>% 
    layout(paper_bgcolor='transparent') %>%
    config(displayModeBar = T) %>% # Kepp Mode bar
    layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ax) # No Axis
  p

}})



 output$tableData <- DT::renderDataTable({
 if (is.null(data())) return()
 if(input$checkbox==FALSE) return(NULL)
 # Try to get the zoomed data
 event.data <- event_data("plotly_zoom", source = "mds")
 # "plotly_relayout" "plotly_zoom"  # : These aren't working
 # Row numbers
 # print(event.data$pointNumber + 1)
 playerData = data()$Dataplayers
 # playerData = print(playerData[event.data$pointNumber + 1,]) # This returns each row as it is clicked. One row at a time can be seen

 playerData %>%
   select(c(1:10)) %>% 
   DT::datatable(rownames= FALSE, options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10), pageLength = 10))})

})
```

Ok so,

a) How do I move the action button (go) 'Plot Players' down further so it is not blocked by the scroll-down list ?

b) I would like the data table to adjust to the zoom of the user. I can get it to work for plotly_click (adjust to the click of the user) but not for plotly_relayout or plotly_zoom. Or would it be an easier option to try use the zoomed points to order the points in the table (i.e. zoomed points at the top of the displayed table) rather than trying to have the table only showing the zoomed points?

c) Is it possible for the hover text to be different from the marker text. I.e. I want: 
marker = "text", text = Initials
hoverinfo = "text", text = paste ("", Player, "Country: " , Country ))
Perhaps adding a trace of initials might be an option?

d) The colour vector is not working properly. 
If you select to plot both girls and boys it works. However if you choose only girls for example when you are selecting the colour no longer is gold or blue. I would like to explicitly say that girls (Sex column = 'F') are plotted in gold and males are in blue.
Here I did it for a non plotly plot: 
  player.col = rep("gold", nrow(playerData)) # let all the rows of dat be coloured gold
  male = which(playerData$Sex=="M") 
  player.col[male] = "blue" # colour this rows = 'M' blue - not gold

As you can see if both boys and girls are not plotted together the colours are pink....

Many thanks

Here is the data to run the code:

```
           Player Initials Age   Country Sex Position Score Score2 Score3 Score4
1    Emily Duffy       ED  22   Ireland   F  Forward     9      3      2      5
2     Jim Turner       JT  26   England   M  Forward     8      4      6      5
3  Rachael Neill       RN  17 Australia   F  Forward     9      6      7      5
4    Andrew Paul       AP  45     Wales   M  Forward     5      7      4      5
5    Mark Andrew       MA  34   Ireland   M  Forward     5      8      5      4
6     Peter Bell       PB  56     Spain   M  Forward     5      7      6      3
7        Amy Coy       AC  77    France   F  Forward     6      6      7      5
8    James Leavy       JL  88  Portugal   M  Forward    10      7      4      5
9   John Connors       JC  87   Hungary   M  Forward     9      7      3      6
10  Paula Polley       PP  62    Russia   F  Forward     8      8      2      6
11  Sarah Turner       ST  23     China   F  Forward    10      9      5      6
12 Kerry McGowan     KMcG  27     Japan   F  Forward     7      6      6      6
13       Liz Foy       LF  71   England   F  Forward     5      6      7      6
14    Ann Mercer       AM  19      Peru   F     Back     4      6      9      6
15 Pete Morrison       PM  70    Norway   M     Back     7      6      8      6
16    Emma Duffy       ED  69    Poland   F     Back     8      6      7      4
17     Lucy Paul       LP  38   Iceland   F     Back     8      4      5      6
18 Rebecca Coyle       PC  43 Greenland   F     Back     9      4      6      6
19     Ben Carey       BC  45   Holland   M     Back     5      3      6      6
```

Answer (score 0):

For you first question I would try smt like this:

```
  dashboardSidebar(
    fluidRow(
    column(6,selectInput("position", label = "Choose    Position", 
    choices = c("Forward" = "Forward", "Back" = "Back"))),
    column(6, offset = 3, actionButton("go", "Plot Players", style = "color: #00004c;"))),
    fluidRow(uiOutput("Player")))
```